# Joomla 3.5 Update from 3.4 Error

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-3.5

I was updating a site and I got the following error message:

Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'PRODUCT' in /home/sitename/public_html/administrator/modules/mod_version/helper.php on line 39

Now the site will not load the administrator interface. I saw this https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/9515 but its not offering a real solution.

The front of the site is still working. Any suggestion would be most helpful!

Comment: I'd recommend you post this as an issue on the Joomla Github Repo as there isn't much we can do here for you at JSE :/

Comment: Agree with @Lodder. If the best Joomla developers which are debugging and improving Joomla on a daily basis, can't help you, it's hard to expect we could do it, regardless of our cumulative experience...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a possible quick workaround - connect via FTP and go to `/administrator/modules/mod_version/` rename it to something like `mod_version-disabled`.

See if at first place resolves the issue with the backend. Generally something didn't went really well with the update and some files might not have been copied/replaced right.

If renaming the above module's folder name, gives you admin access back, then you could try re-installing the Joomla 3.5 by downloading the package from Joomla.org.

If you are still facing problems, you could and should grab a fresh copy of Joomla (unzip the full stable 3.5 package) and manually replace certain directories - but take care to not replace directories that contain additional non-core content.

I mean that usually you can fully replace the includes, layouts folders but for folders like components, modules etc you need to only replace the sub-contents that is part of the core distribution.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine you could update manually by downloading the update package and doing it by uploading the necessary folders and files rather then using the extension manager.

https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/releases/tag/3.5.0